# На физическом форуме не отправляется письмо о подтверждении email'а

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, профиль-участника, почта

Изменил свой email в профиле на phys.sezn.ru. Нажал на "послать мне письмо с проверочной ссылкой", но письмо не пришло. При том, что аналогичное письмо от math.hashcode.ru на тот же ящик было доставлено успешно.

Comment: о каком физическом форуме идет речь?

Comment: @Grundy phys.sezn.ru, очевидно.

Comment: как это относится к SO и SE?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский относится так, что ссылка обратной связи оттуда идет именно сюда, на мету

Comment: @СитниковЮра ну-ка покажи

Comment: http://phys.sezn.ru/contact/ вроде нет

Comment: @Nofate, https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2z12.png

Comment: Ух ты, сеть знаний еще жива? На games.sezn.ru как-то пробовал заходить - залогиниться не дает. А тут залогиниться получилось.

Comment: @insolor Сеть Знаний находится в режиме чтения за исключением сайта Математика и, как оказалось, исключительно по воли случая, сайта Физика.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Добрый день! Большое спасибо за отзыв. Действительно, на сайте были проблемы с исходящими сообщениями. Проблемы исправил.

Comment: А красную метку поставить?