# Какие сайты Сети Знаний существуют?

Tags: поддержка

С http://sezn.ru и http://hashcode.ru делается редирект на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/, однако известно, что некоторые сайты сети ([математика](http://math.hashcode.ru/), [phys](http://phys.sezn.ru), [games](http://games.sezn.ru)) по-прежнему существуют, хотя некоторые и в readonly-режиме.

Хотелось бы увидеть полный список сайтов.

> @insolor Сеть Знаний находится в режиме чтения за исключением сайта Математика и, как оказалось, исключительно по воли случая, сайта Физика.

Nicolas Chabanovsky ♦ [1 час назад](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5772/%d0%9d%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c%d0%bc%d0%be-%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-email%d0%b0#comment21983_5772)

Comment: А если я со своего сайта сделаю редирект на ruSO, о нём тоже можно будет здесь вопросы задавать?

Comment: А вам зачем? Не откапывайте трупы.

Comment: @alexolut, там метассылка ведёт на эту мету: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2z12.png

Comment: @Squidward, а мне любопытно.

Comment: Ну так и я могу метассылку сделать такую. Делов-то.

Comment: @alexolut Сначала вам нужно добавить сайт в этот список: https://web.archive.org/web/20140208050326/http://sezn.ru/

Comment: @Squidward зачем? Мы же на SO, а не на sezn.ru!

Comment: @alexolut, когда были ХэшКодом - были частью sezn, а потом стали частью Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Squidward, и надо быть Николасом

Comment: @insolor ну так были и хватит. Теперь-то уже не часть.